# Flutter: pop all underlying pages in the screen stack

Tags: flutter

Let's say in Flutter, I have a page screen stack at follow. The screen is showing page D, the topmost page.

```
Page D
Page C
Page B
Page A
```

If I do `Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);` on page D, the first line in the the build() method, it will only pop Page C and Page B.

How do I pop page A as well?

Comment: if you pop A, then what you will show? you want to retrigger it?

Comment: It will show Page D, because it is in the rendering process already.

Comment: Try using `Navigator.pop(context)` just after that. It will pop Page A.

Comment: route.isFirst is the page A? if so then when the popUntil gets to page A and notes its the same as route.first it returns true and it won't pop it (it's exclusive), try use 'route.pageD' or some other page that is not in the stack so it pops all

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter the page routes are a stack. In your example D is the top of the stack and A is the bottom. If you pop down to A you have cleared the other three routes from the stack. If you then try to pop A, you will get a black screen because there will be no routes remaining in the stack. If you want to pop A and show D you will need to use Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'D');

Answer (score 0):

From page A, you can call:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                        A.routeName, (route) => route ==
                        A.routeName);
```

I think it's too late to answer your question but it may help others.